# ActiveMQ - Object cannot be recognized when receive from JMS remote host

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, instanceof, activemq-artemis

I am setting up a JMS request reply on two JBoss servers.
In the client, i use camel-jms and Fuse route to create the call.

```java
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.to(camelContext.getEndpoint(JMS_BEANID, JmsQueueEndpoint.class))
```

Basically it will create temporary queue and send to the server.
In the server I create implementation of `MessageListener` to listen to the message.

From debugging view `message.getJMSReplyTo()` returns an instance of `ActiveMQTemporaryQueue`. However, when I try to check `message.getJMSReplyTo() instanceof ActiveMQTemporaryQueue` it returns `false`. I try to create `ActiveMQTemporaryQueue` myself the check returns `true` as expected, e.g.:

```java
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    Destination replyTo = message.getJMSReplyTo();
    if (replyTo instanceof ActiveMQTemporaryQueue) {
        // false, although the debugger show it is ActiveMQTemporaryQueue object
    }
    Destination test = new ActiveMQTemporaryQueue("localhost", "testQueue", (ActiveMQSession)session);
    if (test instanceof ActiveMQTemporaryQueue) {
        // true
    }
}
```

The client and the server are in two different Maven projects (two different war, deployed onto different servers, same workspace).

I don't know what is happening. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using an implementation object (i.e. `ActiveMQTemporaryQueue`)? Why not simply test if `replyTo` is an instance of `javax.jms.TemporaryQueue`?

Comment: Basically i just need to get JMSReplyTo and use messageProducer.send(replyTo, response); to send back data. However inside the send method, it has a check whether the replyTo object is an instance of ActiveMQDestination (ActiveMQTemporaryQueue is subclass of that class). The weird thing is that the check returns false, my block of code above is an illustration of that problem. :(

Comment: You didn't answer my question. *Why* does it have to check if `replyTo` is an instance of `ActiveMQTemporaryQueue`? You don't need to do this just send a message to the destination with a message producer.

Comment: From debugging view, i can see that object is ActiveMQTemporaryQueue. So i try with exactly object return to see what is happening.

Comment: I still no have idea what was happening. But i was managed to make it works by defining a reply queue instead of rely on TemporaryQueue. Thanks for following this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is a classloading issue of some kind, but it's hard to tell with the information you've provided.

That said, I *strongly* recommend that you do not use any implementation objects in your code (i.e. `ActiveMQTemporaryQueue`). If all you're trying to do is a request/reply then there is absolutely no need to use any implementation objects. If you need to know if the value returned by `getJMSReplyTo()` is a temporary queue then you can simply use `replyTo instanceof javax.jms.TemporaryQueue`. If you do that I think your issue will be resolved.